# URLSession capturing not modified HTTP status code

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlcache, urlsession

I am using URLSession with the default useProtocolCachePolicy cache policy. Using a proxy such as Charles I can verify that the caching is working as expected for a request with an Etag where the server is returning a HTTP response of 304 (Not Modified). However the URLSession caching is hiding this response code and instead executing my request completion handlers with a status code of 200 with the cached data. I understand this is as expected as the Foundation libraries are encapsulating this behaviour. However I have a scenario that requires a UI change on a 304 response code.
Is there any delegate or handler I can use to get a peek in to the actual status code before the Foundation libraries do their magic?

One possible workaround is as @ChanchalChauhan has hinted, forcing URLRequest to ignore the local cache (by setting the cache policy to .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData) and manually added the If-None-Match HTTP header with the value extracted from the CachedURLResponse retrieved from the URLCache for the request. However to make this solution complete this logic must only be performed if the cached response has expired, as otherwise a network request is not required. I have not found a way to determine if the cached value has expired.

Comment: try to send last modified date in `If-Modified-Since` key in header of your request.

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan The caching behaviour works fine server side so all the headers required are being sent correctly. My issue is client side (where it is also working correctly) where I want to be notified of a 304 before the Foundation libraries process this response and return the cached data as a 200.

Comment: did you try urlconfig.requestCachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad

Comment: @MAhipalSingh That won't work for me as it will return the cached data (regardless of its expiry) but only make a network request if no cached data exists (not if it is expired).

Comment: Are you getting `Last-Modified` key in your response header?

Comment: Take a look here .. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy?language=objc

NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData